# Can you use the Instagram API to add followers from your own iOS app?

Tags: ios, instagram-api

The Crowdfire app seems to do this. ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4J7nVbCLfI0 )

Pretty much I want users to link their instagram accounts on my app. Then on my app they can add other users on instagram, but from within my app. No transition to instagram, just a simple button you click that will follow somebody.

Is this possible? I know for sharing photos it seemed that you have to transition to instagram. I also saw this github project: https://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit

But it is not clear to me that I can do what I want with InstagramKit.

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Instagram API reference](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/), you can POST a `/users/[other user ID]/relationships` call to follow/unfollow/etc. other users.

> Modify the relationship between the current user and the target user. You need to include an action parameter to specify the relationship action you want to perform. Valid actions are: 'follow', 'unfollow' 'approve' or 'ignore'.